# Groovy csv to string

Tags: csv, groovy, mapping, boomi

I am using Dell Boomi to map data from one system to another.  I can use groovy in the maps but have no experience with it.  I tried to do this with the other Boomi tools, but have been told that I'll need to use groovy in a script.  My inbound data is:

> 132265,Brown
>
> 132265,Gold
>
> 132265,Gray
>
> 132265,Green

I would like to output:

> 132265,"Brown,Gold,Gray,Green"

Hopefully this makes sense!  Any ideas on the groovy code to make this work?

Comment: You should probably read up on Groovy a bit: http://groovy-lang.org/documentation.html

Comment: What format or data type is your incoming data in? Is it a CSV String?

Answer (score 3):

It can be elegantly solved with [`groupBy`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#groupBy(groovy.lang.Closure)) and the *[spread operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_spread_operator)*:

```
@Grapes(
    @Grab(group='org.apache.commons', module='commons-csv', version='1.2')
)

import org.apache.commons.csv.*

def csv = '''
132265,Brown
132265,Gold
132265,Gray
132265,Green
'''

def parsed = CSVParser.parse(csv, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader('code', 'color')
parsed.records.groupBy({ it.code }).each { k,v -> println "$k,\"${v*.color.join(',')}\"" }
```

The above prints:

```
132265,"Brown,Gold,Gray,Green"
```

Comment: Very  nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know how are you getting your data, but here is a general way to achieve your goal. You can use a library, such as the one bellow to parse the csv.

https://github.com/xlson/groovycsv

The example for your data would be:

```
@Grab('com.xlson.groovycsv:groovycsv:1.1')
import static com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser.parseCsv

def csv = '''
132265,Brown
132265,Gold
132265,Gray
132265,Green
'''

def data = parseCsv(csv)
```

I believe you want to associate the number with various values of colors. So for each line you can create a map of the number and the colors associated with that number, splitting the line by ",":

```
map = [:]
for(line in data) {
    number = line.split(',')[0]
    colour = line.split(',')[1]

    if(!map[number])
       map[number] = []

    map[number].add(colour)
}
println map
```

So map should contain:

```
[132265:["Brown","Gold","Gray","Green"]]
```

Well, if it is not what you want, you can extract the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is coming in as a comma separated string of data like this:

> "132265,Brown 132265,Gold 132265,Gray 132265,Green 122222,Red 122222,White"

The following Groovy script code should do the trick.

```
def csvString = "132265,Brown 132265,Gold 132265,Gray 132265,Green 122222,Red 122222,White"

LinkedHashMap.metaClass.multiPut << { key, value ->
    delegate[key] = delegate[key] ?: []; delegate[key] += value
}

def map = [:]
def csv = csvString.split().collect{ entry -> entry.split(",") }
csv.each{ entry -> map.multiPut(entry[0], entry[1]) }

def result = map.collect{ k, v -> k + ',"' + v.join(",") + '"'}.join("\n")
println result
```

Would print:

> 132265,"Brown,Gold,Gray,Green"
>   
>   122222,"Red,White"

Answer (score 0):

Do you HAVE to use scripting for some reason?  This can be easily accomplished with out-of-the-box Boomi functionality.

Create a map function that prepends the ID field to a string of your choice (i.e. 222_concat_fields).  Then use that value to set a dynamic process prop with that value.

The value of the process prop will contain the result of concatenating the name fields.  Simply adding this function to your map should take care of it.  Then use the final value to populate your result.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends upon the data how is it coming. 
If the data which you have posted in the question is coming in a single document, then you can easily handle this in a map with groovy scripting.

If the data which you have posted in the question is coming into multiple documents i.e.
 
doc1: 132265,Brown
doc2: 132265,Gold
doc3: 132265,Gray
doc4: 132265,Green
In that case it cannot be handled into map. You will need to use Data Process Step with Custom Scripting. 
For the code which you are asking to create in groovy depends upon the input profile in which you are getting the data. Please provide more information i.e. input profile, fields etc.