# Splitting csv on comma's except when the string is in quotes

Tags: regex, groovy, soapui

I am having problems splitting up a csv file with data like the following

Cat, car, dog, "A string, that has comma's in it", airplane, truck

I originally tried splitting the file with the following code..

it results in

Cat

car

dog

A string

that has comma's in it

airplane

truck

```
        csvFile.splitEachLine( /,\s*/ ){ parts ->
            tmpMap = [:]
            tmpMap.putAt("column1", parts[0])
            tmpMap.putAt("column2", parts[1])
            tmpMap.putAt("column3", parts[2])
            tmpMap.putAt("column4", parts[3])



            mapList.add(tmpMap)
```

what I would like is

Cat

car

dog

A string, that has comma's in it

airplane

truck

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34888063/groovy-csv-to-string and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995167/groovy-split-csv

Answer (score 0):

You should change your regex a little:

```
def mapList = []
def csvFile = "Cat, car, dog, \"A string, that has comma's in it\", airplane, truck"
​csvFile.splitEachLine( /,(?=(?:[^"]*\"[^"]*")*[^"]*\Z)\s/ ){ parts ->        
    tmpMap = [:]           
    tmpMap.putAt("column1", parts[0])        
    tmpMap.putAt("column2", parts[1])        
    tmpMap.putAt("column3", parts[2])          
    tmpMap.putAt("column4", parts[3])  
    tmpMap.putAt("column5", parts[4]) 
    tmpMap.putAt("column6", parts[5]) 
    mapList.add(tmpMap)
}
​print mapList​
```

But it's better to use already created libraries for that. It will make your life much easier. Take a look at https://github.com/xlson/groovycsv